# Dynamic Linear Models - prior specification

Tags: r, bayesian, dlm

I am using the DLM package to make forecasts for some of my time series.

I wonder how the priors should be elicited. For a Local State space model, one needs to specify the level of data prior to t=1. This is because

```
E(y_t|B_t) = B_t (since the observation equataion looks like y_t = B_t + E_t where E_t is the observation noise)
```

But what if one uses the either the dlmModSeas or dlmModTrig functions? Lets suppose there is a monthly seasonality in my data.

After considering the observation matrix (F) for dlmModSeas, I guess one needs to have information for the level of data prior to t=1. For monthly data, where monthly seasonality is relevant, the priors are the beliefs for the preceding 12-1 = 11 months? Does this hold for dlmModTrig where the observation matrix (F) looks like (1,0,1,0,1,0,....) rather than (1,0,0,0,...)?